# What's the best way to make a multi-user microblogging website?

Tags: php, server-side-scripting

I've an idea of Twitter like website which I am implementing on my own. I'm new to web development so I don't know much about the available tools which can make the work faster. I tried many free twitter clones like status.net but so many changes had to be done in their scripts that I got back to coding the back-end on my own from scratch (using PHP). But are their better ways than coding (the back-end) from scratch?

Comment: you can use Drupal-7.1 for php and another thing is if you want use java you can use liferay-6.1 this is also better option.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Elgg](http://elgg.org). It has a micro blogging plugin, user profile system and all the basic requirements for social networking. You can see an [elgg demo of the default micro blogging plugin here](http://elggdemo.webgalli.com/thewire/all)

Drupal also is a good solution. But you have to customize it for the same result offered by Elgg out of box.

Comment: How hard is to customize Elgg to get an exact twitter clone? (all the features of twitter and not more) And are there any licensing issues? -like will I be able to make my website free from all references to Elgg?

Comment: @user1444680: There is a good learning curve in Elgg. But if you are familiar with MVC architecture, it wont be a problem for you. Otherwise the best solution it to hire a dev/dev team.

Elgg is available in dual licence GPLV2 and MIT. You can remove all back links and references to Elgg.

Answer (score 1):

[WordPress Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) (formerly known as WordPress Multisite or MU or WPMU) could be an option, you should give it a try if you want many sites with the same back-end and still not 50 updates to do on 50 sites but only one. They won't "see" each other easily ([other tutorial for installation](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/07/07/the-ultimate-wordpress-multi-site-network-management-guide/)).

Or [P2 theme](http://p2theme.com/) with its interface close to a microblogging site, if all users have to communicate.

If you want to code it in PHP, then a framework like [Code Igniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) is definitely a time-saver (and more).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Drupal-7.1 for php and another thing is if you want use java you can use liferay-6.1 this is also better option...

Comment: Then I'll have to learn about CMS's first. Surely beneficial in long term.

Comment: yes first you learn and surely it will beneficial in long term..

Comment: What about Wordpress? Compared to Drupal.

Comment: I use only Drupal and liferay both are good but i don't have much idea about WordPress.